# How to update s3fs from v1.74 to latest version in amazon linux 2 or centos?

Tags: amazon-s3, centos, s3fs, amazon-linux-2

I already installed s3fs-fuse v1.74 and my boss need me to update it to latest version, yet I'm a newbie here. I'm using Amazon Linux 2 instance in AWS, sometimes works with centos 7 code too. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

[EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) hosts the latest versions of s3fs.  You can install them on Amazon Linux via:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
sudo yum install s3fs-fuse
```

and CentOS 7 and later via:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install s3fs-fuse
```

These instructions come from the [s3fs README](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse#installation).